# Mapbox javascript : to make a break at the marker that moves (simulation red traffic light)

Tags: javascript, animation, mapbox, marker

how to make a break at my marker like at a red traffic light then start again after,(a short stop) I don't find any tuto on the web.. ( a stop at a random point of the coordinates), it's for a simulation.. I just want to know how we do it..I tried setTimeOut, but it doesn't work.. Thank you for your help !!

```js
var marker1 = new mapboxgl.Marker({
        className: 'marker1'
    }) // Initialize a new marker 
    .setLngLat([6.167361, 45.362544]) // Marker [lng, lat] coordinates
    .addTo(map);

var coords = [
    [6.157903, 45.361839],
    [6.157956, 45.361699],
    [6.161326, 45.363424],
    [6.165399, 45.361447],
    [6.16741, 45.36239],
    [6.167361, 45.362544]

];

var origin = [6.157903, 45.361839];
var waypoint1 = [6.157956, 45.361699];
var waypoint2 = [6.161326, 45.363424];
var waypoint3 = [6.165399, 45.361447];
var waypoint4 = [6.16741, 45.36239];

var destination = [6.167361, 45.362544];
var size = 250;

// implementation of CustomLayerInterface to draw a pulsing dot icon on the map
// see https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#customlayerinterface for more info
var pulsingDot = {
    width: size,
    height: size,
    data: new Uint8Array(size * size * 4),

    // get rendering context for the map canvas when layer is added to the map
    onAdd: function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        this.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    },

    // called once before every frame where the icon will be used
    render: function () {
        var duration = 1000;
        var t = (performance.now() % duration) / duration;

        var radius = (size / 2) * 0.3;
        var outerRadius = (size / 2) * 0.7 * t + radius;
        var context = this.context;

        // draw outer circle
        context.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(
            this.width / 2,
            this.height / 2,
            outerRadius,
            0,
            Math.PI * 2
        );
        context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 200, 200,' + (1 - t) + ')';
        context.fill();

        // draw inner circle
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(
            this.width / 2,
            this.height / 2,
            radius,
            0,
            Math.PI * 2
        );
        context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 100, 100, 1)';
        context.strokeStyle = 'white';
        context.lineWidth = 2 + 4 * (1 - t);
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();

        // update this image's data with data from the canvas
        this.data = context.getImageData(
            0,
            0,
            this.width,
            this.height
        ).data;

        // continuously repaint the map, resulting in the smooth animation of the dot
        map.triggerRepaint();

        // return `true` to let the map know that the image was updated
        return true;
    }
};
// A simple line from origin to destination.
var route = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': [{
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'LineString',
            'coordinates': [origin, waypoint1, waypoint2, waypoint3, waypoint4, destination] // here you can add the additional waypoints
        }
    }]
};

// A single point that animates along the route.
// Coordinates are initially set to origin.
var point = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': [{
        'type': 'Feature',
        'properties': {},
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'Point',
            'coordinates': origin
        }
    }]
};

// Calculate the distance in kilometers between route start/end point.
var lineDistance = turf.length(route.features[0]);

var arc = [];

// Number of steps to use in the arc and animation, more steps means
// a smoother arc and animation, but too many steps will result in a
// low frame rate
var steps = 2500;

// Draw an arc between the `origin` & `destination` of the two points
for (var i = 0; i < lineDistance; i += lineDistance / steps) {
    var segment = turf.along(route.features[0], i);
    arc.push(segment.geometry.coordinates);
}

// Update the route with calculated arc coordinates
route.features[0].geometry.coordinates = arc;

// Used to increment the value of the point measurement against the route.
var counter = 0;

map.on('load', function () {
    map.addImage('pulsing-dot', pulsingDot, {
        pixelRatio: 6
    });
    // Add a source and layer displaying a point which will be animated in a circle.
    map.addSource('route', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': route
    });

    map.addSource('point', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': point
    });

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'route',
        'source': 'route',
        'type': 'line',
        'paint': {
            'line-width': 2,
            'line-color': '#ff8e0a',
            'line-dasharray': [2, 2]
        }
    });


    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'point',
        'source': 'point',
        'type': 'symbol',
        'layout': {
            'icon-image': 'pulsing-dot',
            'icon-allow-overlap': false,
            'icon-ignore-placement': true
        }
    });


    fitMap(map, coords);

    function animate() {

        counter = counter + 1;
        var start =
            route.features[0].geometry.coordinates[
                counter >= steps ? counter - 1 : counter
            ];
        var end =
            route.features[0].geometry.coordinates[
                counter >= steps ? counter : counter + 1
            ];
        if (!start || !end) return;

        // Update point geometry to a new position based on counter denoting
        // the index to access the arc
        point.features[0].geometry.coordinates =
            route.features[0].geometry.coordinates[counter];

        // Calculate the bearing to ensure the icon is rotated to match the route arc
        // The bearing is calculated between the current point and the next point, except
        // at the end of the arc, which uses the previous point and the current point
        point.features[0].properties.bearing = turf.bearing(
            turf.point(start),
            turf.point(end)
        );

        // Update the source with this new data
        map.getSource('point').setData(point);

        // Request the next frame of animation as long as the end has not been reached
        if (counter < steps) {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }

        counter = counter + 1;
    }

    document
        .getElementById('replay')
        .addEventListener('click', function () {
            // Set the coordinates of the original point back to origin
            point.features[0].geometry.coordinates = origin;

            // Update the source layer
            map.getSource('point').setData(point);

            // Reset the counter
            counter = 0;

            // Restart the animation
            animate(counter);
        });

    // Start the animation
    animate(counter);
});

function fitMap(map, coords) {
    var bounds = coords.reduce(function (bounds, coord) {
        return bounds.extend(coord);
    }, new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(coords[0], coords[0]));
    map.fitBounds(bounds, {
        padding: 100
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another waypoint that has the same coordinates as the waypoint before. I have called it `breakpoint` below:

```js
var origin = [6.157903, 45.361839];
var waypoint1 = [6.157956, 45.361699];
var breakpoint = [6.157956, 45.361699];
var waypoint2 = [6.161326, 45.363424];
var waypoint3 = [6.165399, 45.361447];
var waypoint4 = [6.16741, 45.36239];
```

This is how you can add a waypoint to the route

```js
var route = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': [{
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'LineString',
            'coordinates': [origin, waypoint1, breakpoint, waypoint2, waypoint3, waypoint4, destination] // here you can add the additional waypoints
        }
    }]
};
```

---

Now to the animation. The route line is divided into steps. The more steps the smoother.

For each step a coordinate is added to the `arc` object. Between each position in the `arc` the animation will move the marker with equal time.

Therefore to make the marker stop at a position, you have to add coordinates to the `arc` object with the location of the stop.

I am doing this here:

```js
var arc = [];

    // Number of steps to use in the arc and animation, more steps means
    // a smoother arc and animation, but too many steps will result in a
    // low frame rate
    var steps = 500;

    // Draw an arc between the `origin` & `destination` of the two points
    for (var i = 0; i < lineDistance; i += lineDistance / steps) {
        var segment = turf.along(route.features[0], i);
        arc.push(segment.geometry.coordinates);
        
        
        // logic to add additional coordinates to the arc, with coordinates of the waypoint
        if((segment.geometry.coordinates[0] < waypoint1[0] + 0.5 && segment.geometry.coordinates[0] > waypoint1[0] - 0.5) && (segment.geometry.coordinates[1] < waypoint1[1] + 0.5 && segment.geometry.coordinates[1] > waypoint1[1] - 0.5)){
            for(var i2 = 0; i2 < 10; i2 ++){
                arc.push(waypoint1);
            }
        }
    }
    
    //update steps
    steps = arc.length;
```

You can increase the duration to stay at the waypoint, by increasing the number of elements that are pushed into the arc at the position of the waypoint.
Here my full code. Please input YOUR ACCESS TOKEN to run it.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Animate a point along a route</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    .overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
    }

    .overlay button {
        font: 600 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background-color: #3386c0;
        color: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .overlay button:hover {
        background-color: #4ea0da;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@5/turf.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
<div class="overlay">
    <button id="replay">Replay</button>
</div>

<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: [-96, 37.8],
        zoom: 3
    });

    // San Francisco
    var origin = [-122.414, 37.776];

    var waypoint1 = [-100.032, 38.913];
    
    // Washington DC
    var destination = [-77.032, 38.913];
    
    

    // A simple line from origin to destination.
    var route = {
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'features': [
            {
                'type': 'Feature',
                'geometry': {
                    'type': 'LineString',
                    'coordinates': [origin, waypoint1, destination]
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    // A single point that animates along the route.
    // Coordinates are initially set to origin.
    var point = {
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'features': [
            {
                'type': 'Feature',
                'properties': {},
                'geometry': {
                    'type': 'Point',
                    'coordinates': origin
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    // Calculate the distance in kilometers between route start/end point.
    var lineDistance = turf.length(route.features[0]);

    var arc = [];

    // Number of steps to use in the arc and animation, more steps means
    // a smoother arc and animation, but too many steps will result in a
    // low frame rate
    var steps = 500;

    // Draw an arc between the `origin` & `destination` of the two points
    for (var i = 0; i < lineDistance; i += lineDistance / steps) {
        var segment = turf.along(route.features[0], i);
        arc.push(segment.geometry.coordinates);
        
        if((segment.geometry.coordinates[0] < waypoint1[0] + 0.5 && segment.geometry.coordinates[0] > waypoint1[0] - 0.5) && (segment.geometry.coordinates[1] < waypoint1[1] + 0.5 && segment.geometry.coordinates[1] > waypoint1[1] - 0.5)){
            for(var i2 = 0; i2 < 10; i2 ++){
                arc.push(waypoint1);
            }
        }
    }
    
    //update steps
    steps = arc.length;

    // Update the route with calculated arc coordinates
    route.features[0].geometry.coordinates = arc;

    // Used to increment the value of the point measurement against the route.
    var counter = 0;

    map.on('load', function () {
        // Add a source and layer displaying a point which will be animated in a circle.
        map.addSource('route', {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': route
        });

        map.addSource('point', {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': point
        });

        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'route',
            'source': 'route',
            'type': 'line',
            'paint': {
                'line-width': 2,
                'line-color': '#007cbf'
            }
        });

        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'point',
            'source': 'point',
            'type': 'symbol',
            'layout': {
                'icon-image': 'airport-15',
                'icon-rotate': ['get', 'bearing'],
                'icon-rotation-alignment': 'map',
                'icon-allow-overlap': true,
                'icon-ignore-placement': true
            }
        });

        function animate() {
            var start =
                route.features[0].geometry.coordinates[
                    counter >= steps ? counter - 1 : counter
                ];
            var end =
                route.features[0].geometry.coordinates[
                    counter >= steps ? counter : counter + 1
                ];
            if (!start || !end) return;

            // Update point geometry to a new position based on counter denoting
            // the index to access the arc
            point.features[0].geometry.coordinates =
                route.features[0].geometry.coordinates[counter];

            // Calculate the bearing to ensure the icon is rotated to match the route arc
            // The bearing is calculated between the current point and the next point, except
            // at the end of the arc, which uses the previous point and the current point
            point.features[0].properties.bearing = turf.bearing(
                turf.point(start),
                turf.point(end)
            );

            // Update the source with this new data
            map.getSource('point').setData(point);

            // Request the next frame of animation as long as the end has not been reached
            if (counter < steps) {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            }

            counter = counter + 1;
        }

        document
            .getElementById('replay')
            .addEventListener('click', function () {
                // Set the coordinates of the original point back to origin
                point.features[0].geometry.coordinates = origin;

                // Update the source layer
                map.getSource('point').setData(point);

                // Reset the counter
                counter = 0;

                // Restart the animation
                animate(counter);
            });

        // Start the animation
        animate(counter);
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks Moritz, luckily you're here! Should I add something else than the breakpoint ? because the marker doesn't stop..

Comment: You are right Emma, I noticed that the animation does not care about the waypoints. It only cares about the amount of steps and the coordinates that are in the route object.

Comment: @Emma please see my edits in above response. I tested it, it now stops at a waypoint. To make the stop a bit smoother, you can adjust the logic to only trigger when closer to the actual stop.

Comment: Top ! your code works, I admit that I had given up a bit, I looked all over the web, mapbox lacks documentation, tutorials, impossible to find, thank you Moritz for taking the time to help me, I will try to adapt it to my code ...